# ROS2 Galactic rclpy.parameter.Parameter missing floating_point_range and integer_range no longer availabe

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I started using ROS2 Galactic and realized that the parameters 'floating_point_range' and 'integer_range' for rclpy.parameter.Parameter are now missing, yet the rclcpp does have them.

I searched in the changelog but did not find any entry regarding this. Afaik no question has been posted either.

What is the correct way to enforce the ranges in galactic rclpy?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387083/ros2-galactic-rclpy.parameter.parameter-missing-floating_point_range-and-integer_range-no-longer-availabe/) by [lora](https://answers.ros.org/users/76693/lora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer to my own question, leaving here in case someone needs it:

Instead of declaring the ranges in the instantiation of `Parameter` directly, use a `ParameterDescriptor` for it.

---

Originally posted by [lora](https://answers.ros.org/users/76693/lora/) with karma: 26 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0